# mvc4 partial view used twice on the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a partial view for cascading drop downs i.e. Country and State. I am using  the following razor view statement to render this partial view

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PopulateCountriesDropdown", "Helper");}
```

and it works just fine. Following is the complete code for the partial view that makes an asynchronous call to an action method of the controller

```
<pre>@model OnlineExamSystem.Models.CountryAndStateViewModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.c.CountryName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.c.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.cntlist, "CountryId", "CountryName"),"--Select Country--", new {  @class="aha" })
@Html.Label("State")
```

**Note:** since i am unable to write HTML i.e. I have a simple html select for displaying 2nd drop down to show states with `class="ddlstates"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".aha").change(function () {
        var Url = '/Helper/PopulateStateDropdown';
        var catId = $(this).val();
        //alert(catId);
        var select = $('.ddlstate');
        if (catId != '') {
            $.getJSON("/Helper/PopulateStateDropdown", { id: catId },
                function (ddl) {
                    select.empty();
                    select.append($("<option></option>", { value: 0, text: '--Select State--' }));
                    $.each(ddl, function (index, itemData) {
                        select.append($("<option></option>", { value: itemData.Value, text: itemData.Text }));
                    });
                });
        }
        else {
            select.empty();
            select.append($("<option></option>", { value: 0, text: '--Select State--' }));

        }
    });
});
```

as i said this works just fine. but here is the problem i.e. when I try to render the same partial view again on the same page (view) as following

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PopulateCountriesDropdown", "Helper");}
```

the rendering is ok, but changing the country in the 2nd partial view does not select the states properly. Also I have noticed that following action method is called twice for the first partial view

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult PopulateStateDropdown(string id)
{
     var ls = State.GetStateByCountryId(Int32.Parse(id)).AsEnumerable();
     var ddl = ls.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.StateName, Value = m.StateId.ToString() });
     return Json(ddl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and interestingly the the above method is not at all called from the 2nd partial view.

Comment: dropdown event is not called?

Answer (score 1):

`(doucment).ready()` binds event to the dome elements when the page is loaded first time, it finds the elements in DOM and bind events to them, in your case as its a partial view, html is rendered dynamically on page after page is loaded so event is not binded.

Use `live` function for event as you html is dynamically added on the view:

Do like this:

```
$(".aha").live('change',function () {


});
```